# Prevent inner RecyclerView in a ViewPager2 scroll to top after updating data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a ViewPager2 using FragmentStateAdapter and some inner RecyclerView inside the ViewPager2.

I need to update the data in the individual row of the RV. However, whenever I update the adapter, the list scrolls to top automatically which I want to prevent.

The data I'm passing to the FragmentStateAdapter looks like this:

```
[
    ProductWithCategory
        categoryName = String
        products = [
            Product(id, name, code, isSelected),
            Product(id, name, code, isSelected),
            Product(id, name, code, isSelected),
            Product(id, name, code, isSelected)
        ],
    ProductWithCategory
        categoryName = String
        products = [
            Product(id, name, code, isSelected),
            Product(id, name, code, isSelected),
            Product(id, name, code, isSelected),
            Product(id, name, code, isSelected)
        ],
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Note that I'm particularly want to update the `isSelected` field. `categoryName` is used as TabLayout title.

My current solution is to reset the whole adapter to update the whole fragments inside the ViewPager2, hence the scroll to top issue occurs.

I know it should have been done by `notifyDatasetChanged()` inside the RecyclerView adapter, but I don't know how to pass the updated data to the adapter with the model I have above.

```kotlin
    private fun setupTabLayout(productWithCategory: List<ProductWithCategory>) {
        tabMenuBinding.apply {
            val adapter = ProductTypeAdapter(
                fragment = this,
                productWithCategory = productWithCategory
            )
            viewPager.adapter = adapter

            val tabMediator = TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
                tab.text = productWithCategory[position].categoryName
            }
            tabMediator.attach()
        }
    }
```

My FragmentStateAdapter look like this:

```kotlin
class ProductAdapter(
    fragment: Fragment,
    private val products: List<ProductWithCategory>
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    override fun getItemCount() = products.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return ProductsFragment(products[position].products) 
    }
}
```

In the RecyclerView adapter looks like this:

```kotlin
class ProductsFragment(
    private val products: List<Products>
) : BaseFragment() {

    override fun getLayoutRes(): Int = R.layout.fragment_list_item

    override fun setupView(view: View) {
        val adapter = ListItemAdapter(products)
        binding.rvList.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

How can I update the data of the inner RecyclerView to prevent auto-scroll to top when adapter is reset?

Comment: hmmm, what is the question? the one in the body or in the title ? (*Prevent inner RecyclerView in a ViewPager2 scroll to top after updating data* or *How can I update the data of the inner RecyclerView from outside of the ViewPager2 adapter?*)

Comment: @Selvin You're right, it's confusing. The question is more to the title, but the implementation is explained in the body. I have updated the question at the bottom to tell what I want to achieve.

Comment: i guess notifyDatasetChanged is culprit. Use Diffutils or  ( notifyItemRangeChanged/removed/inserted, notifyItemChanged/removed/inserted)

Comment: How about this, each item has its own viewModel, once the product is selected in your Rv, you call it's viewModel method which sets the isSelected field in your repo, and you observe live data in the bindview holder which update the view!